# Node js :: How can I update a single field using aggregation framework?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using Robo3t and writing a query to update all documents. It works fine. But How can I write the same query in mongo compass. I have to use aggregate pipeline.

```
db.getCollection('model').updateMany({"status" : 2 , "expiry" : { $lt : new Date("2022-01-13")} , "type" : "msisdn" ,"redemptionDateTime" : null, "refundTransactionID" : null }, { $set: {"status" : NumberInt(1) }})
```

I have been doing something like this. But its not updating the results. What am I missing ?

```
db.getCollection('model').aggregate(
[
        {   $match: {
                    "status" : 2 , 
                    "expiry" : { $lt : new Date("2022-01-13")} ,
                    "type" : "msisdn" ,
                    "redemptionDateTime" : null,
                    "refundTransactionID" : null
                    }
         }, 
         { $set: {
                      "status": NumberInt(1)
                    }
         }
]
)
```

Comment: the question is how to write a query in mongodb compass that does what the first query does? aggregation is not update, it normally returns the results to the client (unless you have out or merge stage).

Comment: aggregation does not update any document in collection, it will format the result only, use compass shell for update query,